# WCF, client projects : how to launch both but only debug the client?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, wcf, debugging, breakpoints

In visual studio, I have a WCF project which is ran in a local IIS server, and a client project that I want de debug. Then I launch the WCF project in debug mode, close it in VS (it stays opened in the windows task bar), put my breakpoints in the client project, and then launch debugging of the client project.

I have to tell you that the client is given a list of files that it parses one after the other.
It seems to work well, but after an given amount of time (a few minutes),  the following file enters in the debugging. sorry if it is not very clear, I try to explain it the best.
To explain it in more details, The files are provided to the client, and each file is first treated by an entry method, say A(). I have a breakpoint in the first line of A(), and while debugging this method and those which follow, suddenly, after a "F10" (one step ahead), the cursos go to the A()'s breakpoint and the 2 calls of A() are concurrent.

I tried to launch the web service in RELEASE, but then I can't launch the client(a visual studio message box complains the service isn't in debug mode).

Do you know a way to run both projects but only debug the client?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Select the solution in Solution Explorer and then select the Properties icon in the toolbar, or right-click the solution and select Properties.
On the Properties page, select Common Properties > Startup Project.
[image]

If the server does not need debugging, set the server project to "Start without debugging" and set a breakpoint on the client, then start the project.
If you want to know more about debugging in VS, you can refer to the links below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/debugger/debug-multiple-processes?view=vs-2019